# is there a guide or link for learning how to create this xml view?

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

Hi I know it is maybe a simple question but i dont know what to search to find my question 
I want to create this bottom navigation view which i can do create bottom navigation in android

but as obvious in the second photo when we hold our finger on button it happen to something that i cant create and I want you to help to create or link to some guide for creating this:
[button in bottom navigation that expands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GpUQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to update the dependency

```
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’
```

Design for bottom navigation https://xmleditoronline.org/?id=ac92e01a0aa54dbd376795b4742a41ba-S2nSrO

And here is how you should format the items under them **https://xmleditoronline.org/?id=ac92e01a0aa54dbd376795b4742a41ba-1dKLUF**

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_schedules:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_music:

                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
});
```